# Big O notation: removing big O from denominator

Tags: asymptotics, numerical-analysis

In *A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations* (page 26) Arieh Iserles gives the following derivation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\rho(w)}{\ln(w)}=\frac{\xi+\xi^2}{\xi-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\frac{1}{3}\xi^3+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{4})}=\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}+\mathcal{O(\xi^3)}
\end{equation}
where $\xi=w-1$, $\rho(w)=w^2-w$ and $\xi\to 0$. I understand the expansion of the logarithm in the denominator, but how does the second step work? I have no idea how this big O is removed from the denominator. Can anyone explain this please?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start out simple:

$${1 \over 1 + x} = 1 - x + x^2 - \cdots$$

so it follows that

$${1 \over 1 + O(x)} = 1 + O(x)$$

as $x \to 0$.

(Background: I interpret $O(x)$ as representing any function $f(x)$ where $|f(x)|$ is asymptotically no larger than $x$, i.e., there exist constants $c_0,x_0$ such that $|f(x)| \le c_0 |x|$ for all $-x_0 \le x \le x_0$.  This is the likely meaning of big-O notation in this context, where we are concerned about the asymptotic behavior as $x \to 0$ and where values can be either positive and negative.   If it looks a little different from what you are used to in computer science, that's because in CS we most commonly deal with the situation where we have a function $f(n)$ where $n \to \infty$ and where all values are positive, so the definition looks a bit different in that context.)

Now suppose $v=O(1)$, and take a more complex expression:

$${1 \over 1 + v + O(x)} = {1 \over 1+v} \cdot {1 \over 1 + O(x)} = {1 \over 1+v}(1 + O(x)) = {1 \over 1+v} + O(x),$$

where I have used that $v \cdot O(x)=O(x)$, etc.

Finally, if $u=O(1)$, we can multiply both sides by $1+u$ to see that

$${1+u \over 1+v+O(x)} = {1+u \over 1+v} + O(x).$$

Now plug in $x=\xi^3$ and $u = \xi$ and $v = -\frac12 \xi + \frac13 \xi^2$, and we obtain

$$
\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{3})}=\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}+\mathcal{O(\xi^3)}
$$

which is the step of the derivation you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now realize the obvious: that these expressions are $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Thanks for the clean simple explanation, big help.

Answer (score 2):

Let us compute the difference.

$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\xi+\xi^2}{\xi-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\frac{1}{3}\xi^3+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{4})} -\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}\\
=&\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{3})} -\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}\\
=&(1+\xi)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{3})} -\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}\right)\\
=&(1+\xi)\frac{-\mathcal{O}(\xi^3)}{(1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2+\mathcal{O}(\xi^{3}))(1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2)}\\
=&(1+\xi)\frac{-\mathcal{O}(\xi^3)}{1-\mathcal{O}(\xi)}\\
=&-\mathcal{O}(\xi^3)\frac{1+\xi}{1-\mathcal{O}(\xi)}\\
=&-\mathcal{O(\xi^3)}\\
=&\mathcal{O(\xi^3)}
\end{aligned}$$

Just in case it is confusing, $\mathcal{O}(f(\xi))$ for a function $f$ of $\xi$ just means some function of $\xi$ whose absolute value is smaller than $c|f(\xi)|$ for some constant $c>0$ when $\xi$ is near 0 enough. It might mean a different function at each of its occurrence above.

Comment: I presume the second to last step is just inputting the limit $\xi\to 0$, which then gives $\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Comment: @Simon, yes, in the second to last step we use the fact that the last term, that fraction becomes 1 (or $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which happens to be good enough as well) if we take the limit ξ→0. The last step just means, if a function is asymptotic not larger than $\xi^3$ in the sense of absolute values, then so is its negative function. We can obtain a more precise computation by replacing $\mathcal{O}$ with $\Theta$ (and attaching some constant factors) throughout.